# Setting style views programmatically/dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout

I am building a library and would like to know how to programmatically style my views. I have done lengthy research but I haven't found a solution. I have the code below in my styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><resources>
<style name="LibTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="PreviewStyle" parent="LibTheme">
    <item name="android:background">@color/back_</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:text">@string/preview</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">end</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">10dp</item>
</style>
<style name="DescriptionStyle" parent="LibTheme">
    <item name="android:background">@color/back_</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:text">@string/desc</item>
</style>
```

`
This works well with the code below:

```
Context themedContext = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(),
            R.style.DescriptionStyle);
    Context themedContext2 = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(),
            R.style.PreviewStyle);
    TextView desc = new TextView(themedContext);
    TextView preview = new TextView(themedContext2);
```

but position attributes like `<item name="android:layout_gravity">end</item>`are not working so the view remains distorted. How can I do this correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no need to create a style. You can set gravity by this
`textView.setGravity(Gravity.END);`

Comment: Gravity.END sets the gravity for the text inside the textview not the view itself, I need the text view to be at the end of the parent

Comment: Then set Gravity to your parent view.
Share your layout XML file. I may help you

Comment: Am creating the view dynamically in the library, not using xml

Comment: You can dynamically set Gravity to your parent view. `parentView.setGravity(Gravity.END)`

Comment: `LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;

textView.setLayoutParams(params);`